# Django сортировка

Tags: django, queryset, order-by

Задача отсортировать по совпадению.
Есть модель поставщика Retailer с полем city
Пример:
Поставщик1 имеет city = Москва, а Поставщик2 имеет city = Воронеж и т.п.

Необходимо отсортировать результаты queryset полю city, в начале должны идти те что в городе Москва, потом уже любые другие.
Вариант с фильтрацией не подходит хотелось бы именно отсортировать.
Прошу помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй с `Case/When`

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, IntegerField

Retailer.objects.annotate(
    city_order=Case(
        When(city="Москва", then=Value(1)),
        default=2,
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )
).order_by('city_order')
```

Comment: Отлично, все получилось, спасибо.